# longest increasing subsequence of a set of disjoint decreasing sequences

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Lets say we have some disjoint decreasing sequences:

```
s1={10,8,2}
s2={9,5,4,1}
s3={7,6,3}
```

I select some decreasing sequences (say 5 decreasing sequences in the order `s2`,`s1`,`s2`,`s3`,`s2`) and concatenate them (resulting sequence `S = {9,5,4,1,10,8,2,9,5,4,1,7,6,3,9,5,4,1}`.

Now I want to find the **length of the longest increasing subsequence in S**. In the above example: `5` -> `{1,2,4,7,9}`

Expected Time Complexity is less than **O(|S|)**.

Comment: The best solution if the numbers are random is in `O(|S|*log(|S|))` using dynamic programming. You can try to start from there and add some restrictions according to your decreasing order. For instance, you can "remove" `9, 5, 4` (beginning) and `5, 4, 1` (end). Also, don't iterate normally through the sequence, because when you take `1`, you need to find the lowest number from the second sequence that is bigger than `1` ... I mean start from right to left in the next sequence `2` - `8` - `10`.

Comment: You cannot do better than ` `O(|S|*log(|S|))`; if you could you would be able to solve the unrestricted LIS problem simply by assuming `s_i={S[i]}` (all single-element subsequences). You need to set up further restrictions.

Comment: I can't seem to think of any solution better than O(|S| * log(k)) where k is the average size of the decreasing sequences. Though it might be useful to use some sort of line sweep type algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

The length of the longest increasing subsequence can't be more than two. Because the sequences you concatenate are decreasing, it can only be an increasing sequence if you go from the last number of one sequence to the first number of the other sequence. To find out if there is an increasing subsequence with length 2 in your sequence S, you only have to focus on the end and the beginning of the sequences you want to concatenate.

Comment: {1,2,4,7,9} is the longest LIS here. The maximum possible length of LIS is equal to number of decreasing sequences concatenated to form S which is 5 (at most 1 number can be present from each decreasing sequence to form an increasing subsequence).

Comment: A subsequence is not defined like you think it is. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence